# push content up on button click (flutter)

Tags: flutter, animation, layout

how can I push page content up like the effect that happens when the keyboard appear??
something like this in the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRbLD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `showModalBottomSheet` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html).

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  context: context,
  builder: ((context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.color,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
          topRight: Radius.circular(20),
        ),
      ),
      child: const Container(), // Child content
    );
  }),
);
```

Comment: this is nice solution but the problem is that showModalBottomSheet appear above the content 
but I need somthing to raise the con tent up

Comment: Can't you use a stateful widget plus a state based shown Container ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a bool to know if the button has been pressed.

```
bool buttonPushed = false;
```

Then when the button is pressed do this:

```
setState(() {
buttonPressed = true;
});
```

Show a `Stack` as your `Scaffold` body with the first child being the opening screen with the button. Then as the second child put an `AnimatedContainer` with the `height: buttonPressed ? <height you want for the sheet> : 0` and inside that `AnimatedContainer` put the sheet content.

It would look something like this:

```
Widget scaffold() {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        screenWithButton(),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
            height: buttonPressed ? 500 : 0, //Edit this height as you want
            child: loginFormSheet(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```